# Removing grey border from form input on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

http://i55.tinypic.com/3325gyo.png

This grey border appears when you focus on the text field. I've tried outline: 0 which doesn't remove it. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: That is not normal, the normal Chrome focus outline color is orange. It must be coming from your own styles. Use Chrome's builtin inspector and see where the style is coming from. Also, accept some answers.

Comment: I was overlooking the obvious with the inspector. The solution is the box-shadow css property. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can do like this:

`input:focus {outline: none;}`

Comment: I have that also (forgot to put it in my post). It doesn't seem to be the answer either.

Comment: @allanb - I don't see a reason how you're getting the borders on focus then, also, the chrome's focus border is orange color but the one in the image is gray. Can you share some css? Also, what's the status on other browsers? Firefox/IE?

Comment: The culprit is the css property 'box-shadow':

`:focus {
 outline: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
 -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
}`

Comment: allanb has the answer just above here!

Comment: allanb's answer needs a lot more attention!

Comment: I needed: `:active:focus {outline: none;}`

Answer (score 2):

There is a grey border that is automatic in chrome but it is just a regular border. Get the class or Id of the input and just put border:none; The input:focus as someone else has said is the selector to remove the border on focus. Hope this helps someone, automattic styles can be a nuisance sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by styling the tag:

```
<fieldset>
```

to `border: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

As said by allanb [in the comments of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755544/4074148), the culprit is the css property `'box-shadow'`:

```
:focus {
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```