# Get rid of <select> grey border in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I only have the bottom border on my select element but a grey border shows up which I cannot get rid of.

**CSS:**

```
select {

width: 100px;
padding: 10px;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
background-color: black;
color: white;
outline: none;   

}
```

Screenshot of
[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iLC7.png).
(the grey border)

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Select`s are badly editable by CSS. Not crossbrowser.

Comment: ^ That doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: @OscarPeace: remove top, left and right border. They are there by defaults.

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755509/removing-grey-border-from-form-input-on-chrome) Here you can find the answer bro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
 </select>
```